# Send stream from getUserMedia to a nodejs BackEnd and Resend it to google-cloud-platform speech API

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project where we need to user the google-cloud-platform speech API, so I use getUserMedia to get the MediaStream, but I don't know what to send from it to the BackEnd.

On the Back End I have a simple server nodeJs with socket.io, socket.io-stream and the google speech API.

I'm on the second case of the [google speech API doc](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-nodejs).
I want to send the stream to the back End and resend it to the google speech API. I really don't want to record an audio file and don't want for security reason to send the stream directly from my FrontEnd to google.

**Front End**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Context } from "./types/context";
import { KdSchema } from './types/kdschema/kd-schema';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import * as ss from 'socket.io-stream';
declare var { navigator }: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'test-root',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent {
    stream: MediaStream;
    server = 'http://localhost:5000';
    socket;
    socketStream;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.server);
        this.socket.emit('connection');
        this.socketStream = ss.createStream();
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    }

    startRecording() {
        const mediaSession = {audio: true, video: false};

        const successCallback = (stream: MediaStream) => {
            this.stream = stream;
            ss(this.socket).emit('audioStream', stream.getAudioTracks[0] );
        }

        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia(mediaSession, successCallback, (err) => console.log(err));
        } else {
            console.log('Error: getUserMedia not supported !');
        }
    }

    stopRecording() {}
}
```

**Back End**

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http');
let io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
let socketStream = require('socket.io-stream');
let Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')(MY CREDENTIAL);


// The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';

// The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;

// The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
const languageCode = 'fr';

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode
    },
    interimResults: false // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = Speech.streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('data', data => {
        console.log(data[0]);
    }).on('error', err => console.log('Error: ', err));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socketStream(socket).on('audioStream', stream => {
        console.log(stream);
    });
});
```

My question is, what I have to send to the Back End ?

Comment: can you do something like stream.pipe(recognizeStream) from within the `socketStream(socket.on('audioStream', ...` block?

Comment: No, that throw an error, the MediaStream object is for sure not right thing to send without any work on it, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes: one to your recognizeStream and one to your socket.io-stream

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http');
let io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
let socketStream = require('socket.io-stream');
let Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')(MY CREDENTIAL);


// The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';

// The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;

// The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
const languageCode = 'fr';

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode
    },
    interimResults: false // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = Speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
    .on('data', data => {
        console.log("Receiving data!!!!!!"); 
        console.log(data[0]);
    }).on('error', err => console.log('Error: ', err));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socketStream(socket).on('audioStream', stream => {
        //console.log(stream);
        console.log("Got a stream");
        stream.pipe(recognizeStream);
    });
});
```

If this doesn't work, pipe your stream to a file and use something like audacity to check what the hertz is for the file. I ran into issues in the past when trying to send google wav files while specifying the wrong hertz and/or encoding.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for the backend. Now I have to figure it out what to send from the front end.

Comment: Yes, I've reacted to this issue, it is helpful but still I can't make it work. But thanks.

Comment: One other thing I ran into in the past, at one point Chrome required https in order to access the microphone. Not sure if this is still the case or not. Try using Firefox or create some certs to test using https.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the tips mate !